# Microservice Portal restarted after executing my endpoint

Tags: c#, docker, linux-kernel, .net-6.0, tiff

I have an endpoint that is used to generate invoices. Essentially, this endpoint first retrieves the invoice data from the database. After certain validation, it generates the invoice in the respective format, usually TIFF, PDF, DOC, TXT, etc.

The problem arises when attempting to generate the invoice in TIFF format. In the middle of the request processing, as per the log information below, my application gets restarted. I am not what might be happened, even I have added loggers in the respective code, but nothing is logged.

```
Hosting environment: Development

Dec 4, 2023 @ 23:46:05.518  INFO    Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.

Dec 4, 2023 @ 23:46:05.518  DEBUG   Hosting started

Dec 4, 2023 @ 23:46:05.518  INFO    Content root path: \/home\/app

Dec 4, 2023 @ 23:46:05.377  INFO    DiagnosticObserver TraceDiagnosticObserver Subscribed to Microsoft.AspNetCore

Dec 4, 2023 @ 23:46:05.375  INFO    Now listening on: http:\/\/[::]:8080

Dec 4, 2023 @ 23:46:05.132  WARN    No XML encryptor configured. Key {7f9962c8-aaa3-4267-844d-948456} may be persisted to storage in unencrypted form.

Dec 4, 2023 @ 23:46:05.104  INFO    Creating key {7f9962c8-aaa3-4267-844d-a03662943254} with creation date 2023-12-04 18:16:05Z, activation date 2023-12-04 18:16:05Z, and expiration date 2024-03-03 18:16:05Z.

Dec 4, 2023 @ 23:46:05.094  INFO    Started

Dec 4, 2023 @ 23:46:04.974  INFO    Starting

Dec 4, 2023 @ 23:46:04.963  INFO    Starting HeartBeat

Dec 4, 2023 @ 23:46:04.879  WARN    Neither user profile nor HKLM registry available. Using an ephemeral key repository. Protected data will be unavailable when application exits.

Dec 4, 2023 @ 23:46:04.879  WARN    Using an in-memory repository. Keys will not be persisted to storage.

Dec 4, 2023 @ 23:46:04.863  DEBUG   Hosting starting

Dec 4, 2023 @ 23:46:00.667  INFO    Located environment: test_api, dev, twetwtwt_32, 843fsdjbjdsfgdszxn , (null)

Dec 4, 2023 @ 23:46:00.439  INFO    Fetching config from server at: http:\/\/testet.com:8\/enterprise\/config

Dec 4, 2023 @ 23:46:00.437  INFO    Located environment: test_api, dev, twetwtwt_32, 843fsdjbjdsfgdszxn, (null)

Dec 4, 2023 @ 23:46:00.214  INFO    Fetching config from server at: http:\/\/testet.com:8\/enterprise\/config

Dec 4, 2023 @ 23:46:00.197  INFO    Located environment: test_api, dev, twetwtwt_32, 843fsdjbjdsfgdszxn, (null)

Dec 4, 2023 @ 23:45:59.839  INFO    Fetching config from server at: http:\/\/testet.com:80\/enterprise\/config

Dec 4, 2023 @ 23:45:58.077  INFO    Bitmap to tiff compression started

Dec 4, 2023 @ 23:45:52.777  INFO    HTML to tiff conversion started

Dec 4, 2023 @ 23:45:52.748  INFO    Invoice generatio for tiff started : 4327433

Dec 4, 2023 @ 23:45:52.745  INFO
```

Here is the line of code I believe issue is causing.

```
private void SaveBitmapImageToTiffCompression(Image bitmapImage, Stream tiffStream)
{
    try
    {
        Logger.Log(NLog.LogLevel.Info, "Bitmap to tiff compression started");

        using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            bitmapImage.Save(stream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp);
            var imageStream = stream.ToArray();

            using (var image = SixLabors.ImageSharp.Image.Load(imageStream))
            {

                image.Save(tiffStream, new TiffEncoder
                {
                    Compression = TiffCompression.Lzw

                });
                ;
            }
        }

        Logger.Log(NLog.LogLevel.Info, "Bitmap to tiff compression finished");


    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Logger.Log(NLog.LogLevel.Error, $"Bitmap to tiff compression failed with exception {ex}");

        // Fallback on Drawing.commons behavior
        bitmapImage.Save(tiffStream, ImageFormat.Tiff);
    }
}
```

Please, if anyone has an idea on this, suggest any solution.

Note: The endpoint is developed in .NET 6 and hosted in a Linux environment. It works perfectly on my Windows machine and Linux environment for all other formats except TIFF.